# The right size of my cpvc pipe

Tags: leak, pipe, cpvc

I have a leaked cpvc pipe and I asked a question the other day. [bathroom pipe joint leakage behind the ceiling tiles](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/112866/61877), now I am searching a new pipe for replacement, I thought the pipe is 3/4", as shown below (if you enlarge the image you might be able to see the spec of dimensions)

[image]

Therefore I went to Lowe's and bought a 3/4", and it turned out to be bigger, then I changed to 1/2" and it's still a little bigger. So what's exactly the right size?

Comment: I didn't know what is that so I googled. Schedule 80 seems to have thicker wall, so mine could be 80. So can I say, schedule 40 with 3/4"is the right one?

Comment: I was thinking schedule 40 / 80 but the fittings should be the same. Is the wall thickness .01 that sounds way thin for pipe. I think it should be closer to .1 or larger but I do more conduit than water pipe.

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch, Ed. I will bring in the old pipe to lowes to find out

Comment: I typed the skew and it said it was 3/4 cpvc. Not sure why your new pipe is different.

Comment: Have you already cut the pipe? Are you trying to join old and new pipe together? Have you bought the correct bits & pieces to join them?